Auth isn't being read in AdonisJS. What could be the problem?
My code won't recognize "auth.user", and therefore, any of it's properties (user id is the one I'm trying to use).
This method searches for register created by users of the same institution as the current user. But "auth.user.id_user", which I'm using for identifying who the user is, and which institution he belongs to, won't work. The answer is always "cannot read properties of undefined". Any idea on what it could be?
`public async selectAll( { auth }:any ){
let admin = (await Administrator.query().where("id_user", auth.user.id_user))[0]
const events = await Event
.query()
.from('events as e')
.select('e.*')
.join('administrators as a', 'e.responsible', 'a.id_institution')
.where('a.id_institution', admin.id_institution)
return {
    success: true,
    events: events
}

}`
